# Add elements of a tuple to elements of an array

Tags: c++

I have a template which receives an array of Eigen 3D vectors and a variadic template of Eigen expressions which can be added to a vector.

I want to sum the ith element of the variadic argument to the ith element of the array.

I have tried something like this

```
template <int N, typename... TCorrs>
void operator()(std::array<Vector3 *, N> xs;, TCorrs &&...acc)
{
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(acc...);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        *(xs[i]) += std::get<i>(tup);
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, as `i` is not a constant expression and therefore it can't be used for `std::get<>`.

What would be the best way to do this? In my actual code I can ensure that I have the same amount of elements in the array and in the variadic argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to iterate over each member of the pack and have it added to the corresponding array element.  That would look like

```
// also change N to be of the type std::size_t as that is the type of the array size
template <std::size_t N, typename... TCorrs>
void operator()(std::array<Vector3 *, N> xs;, TCorrs &&...acc)
{
    std::size_t i = 0; 
    ((xs[i++] += acc), ...); // this says do (xs[i++] += acc) for each acc
}
```

and you can see it working in this [simplified example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c48d7ced4bc2948)

Comment: I think I need to spend some time trying to parse and understand how fold expressions work. This is super elegant!

Comment: @jjcasmar They are super nice and make working with variadic templates a lot easier.

Comment: I have experiment a bit with the code you provided, giving more values to the variadic than the ones on the array. I would have expected a compile error, but compiles and runs fine. Can you explain it? example here https://godbolt.org/z/edKW9evYx

Comment: @jjcasmar A fold expression tells the compiler to do whatever operation for each member of the parameter pack.  In this case the operation is the comma operator because we have `(expr, ...)`.  So `expr` will be expanded out like `(expr1, expr2, expr..., exprN)`.  In the case of my example code `((xs[i++] += acc), ...)` literally gets replaced with `(xs[0] += 3, xs[1] += 4, xs[2] += 5)`

Comment: @jjcasmar If you are talking about how you passed 4 elements when the array only has 3 well that puts you in undefined behavior land and all outcomes are correct at that point.  You can stop that from happening by adding a `static_assert` in the form of `static_asser(N == sizeof...(acc));`